# PHP DOMdocument echoing problem

Tags: php, domdocument

```
$content = '<!--<sup><span style="font-weight:bold;color:black;">0</span></sup><br/>-->
    <div class="popular-video-image">
        <a href="video/Far+East+Movement - Like+a+G6/w4s6H4ku6ZY/" title="<lang video_go_to=Far East Movement - Like a G6>">
            <img src="/images/topvideo/1.jpg" alt=""/>
        </a>
        <span class="popular-video-artist ellipsis"><a href="video/Far+East+Movement - Like+a+G6/w4s6H4ku6ZY/" title="<lang video_go_to=Far East Movement - Like a G6>" class="ellipsis">Far East Movement</a></span>
        <span class="popular-video-title ellipsis"><a href="video/Far+East+Movement - Like+a+G6/w4s6H4ku6ZY/" title="<lang video_go_to=Far East Movement - Like a G6>" class="ellipsis">Like a G6</a></span>
    </div>';

    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    $dom->loadHTML($content);
    foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $node)
    {
        $node->setAttribute('href', 'http://mysite.ru/' . $node->getAttribute('href'));
    }
    $dom->formatOutput = true;

    echo $dom->saveXml($dom->documentElement);
```

**Output:**

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="popular-video-image">&#13;
        <a href="http://mysite.ru/video/Far+East+Movement - Like+a+G6/w4s6H4ku6ZY/" title="&lt;lang video_go_to=Far East Movement - Like a G6&gt;">&#13;
            <img src="/images/topvideo/1.jpg" alt=""/></a>&#13;
        <span class="popular-video-artist ellipsis"><a href="http://mysite.ru/video/Far+East+Movement - Like+a+G6/w4s6H4ku6ZY/" title="&lt;lang video_go_to=Far East Movement - Like a G6&gt;" class="ellipsis">Far East Movement</a></span>&#13;
        <span class="popular-video-title ellipsis"><a href="http://mysite.ru/video/Far+East+Movement - Like+a+G6/w4s6H4ku6ZY/" title="&lt;lang video_go_to=Far East Movement - Like a G6&gt;" class="ellipsis">Like a G6</a></span>&#13;
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

I do not want to add html and body tags. Also do not want to tag  replaced to `&lt;lang&gt;` . `And &#13;` is also unnecessary.

I want to receive such content, which was at the entrance, only with modified links..

Sorry for bad english!

Answer (score 4):

You are seeing `&#13;` at the end of each line because your HTML has [Windows-style line endings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representations) `CR+LF`. To get rid of them, run this on it before you feed it into `DOMDocument`  — to convert them to Unix-style line endings `LF`:

```
$content = preg_replace('/\r\n/', "\n", $content);
```

Answer (score 3):

saveXml takes an optional parameter to allow you to specify the node to output.

```
$dom->saveXml($dom->documentElement->firstChild->firstChild);
```

This will remove the html and body tags from the output.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the `<html>` and `<body>` tags get placed in because you are using `loadHTML`. Try using `loadXML` instead.

As for `&lt;lang&gt;`, it *has* to be replaced because otherwise the resulting XML would not be valid. If it is causing you problems, you should change your approach a little and work with it, not against it.

Comment: I need a way out by using DomDocument

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $content = '<!--<sup><span style="font-weight:bold;color:black;">0</span></sup><br/>-->
    <div class="popular-video-image">
        <a href="video/Far+East+Movement - Like+a+G6/w4s6H4ku6ZY/" title="<lang video_go_to=Far East Movement - Like a G6>">
            <img src="/images/topvideo/1.jpg" alt=""/>
        </a>
        <span class="popular-video-artist ellipsis"><a href="video/Far+East+Movement - Like+a+G6/w4s6H4ku6ZY/" title="<lang video_go_to=Far East Movement - Like a G6>" class="ellipsis">Far East Movement</a></span>
        <span class="popular-video-title ellipsis"><a href="video/Far+East+Movement - Like+a+G6/w4s6H4ku6ZY/" title="<lang video_go_to=Far East Movement - Like a G6>" class="ellipsis">Like a G6</a></span>
    </div>';

    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    $dom->loadHTML($content);
    foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $node)
    {
        $node->setAttribute('href', 'http://mysite.ru/' . $node->getAttribute('href'));
    }
    $dom->formatOutput = true;

    echo preg_replace('#^<!DOCTYPE.+?>#', '', str_replace( array('<html>', '</html>', '<body>', '</body>', "\n\n", '&lt;', '&gt;'), array('', '', '', '', '', '<', '>',), $dom->saveHTML()));
```